# Are there any web-based Linux image builders that allow selection of preinstalled packages?

Tags: linux

I know of one: The Angstrom Linux distribution has an [online builder](http://narcissus.angstrom-distribution.org/) (called Narcissus) that allows you to select what applications you want preinstalled in the OS, then builds a working image of it for you to download and run from a flash drive.

Is there anything like that for more popular distributions like Red Hat, Fedora, Ubuntu, or Debian? I think this would be particularly useful for virtual appliances and server deployment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is [SuSEStudio](http://susestudio.com/), you can download an ISO (or I believe an IMG file)

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used it, but how about this?

http://lifehacker.com/5588211/how-to-create-your-own-customized-ubuntu-live-cd

That's for Ubuntu, but there should be similar things for RPM-based distros.